# Enable/Disable Javascript in Firefox 23

Tags: javascript, firefox

How to enable/disable JavaScript in Firefox-23.

I did check the [release notes of Firefox-23](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/23.0/releasenotes/) it says, `"Enable JavaScript" preference checkbox has been removed and user-set values will be reset to the default`.

I have been using the enable/disable JavaScript feature to check if my **developing website** behaves as expected without JS. How do I disable JavaScript now.  As of now am using [web developer add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/), but, I don't want to use it as it fills most of my webpage. Looking for an alternative.

Why this feature was removed.?

Comment: this isn't programming related.

Comment: where can I get the answer for this?

Comment: i think someone should transfer it to superuser section

Comment: ask the firefox community. https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/get-community-support

Comment: This is related to web development.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Releases/23 says:

> You may still disable JavaScript by double clicking the "javascript.enabled" option in about:config.

Other choices are the noscript plugin, or [next generation devtools](https://twitter.com/davidbruant/status/351415593141940224).

> Why this feature was removed?

See [Bug 851702](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=851702) and the linked ones, especially [*Get rid of options that kill our product*](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=851698) ("[checkboxes that kill](http://limi.net/checkboxes-that-kill)").

Comment: Them removing the option seems similar to the idea to add automatic breaking mechanism to cars when the driver has alcohol in their blood. It will not care if your life is in danger and you have to get off the railroad tracks. To quote: _The road to hell is paved with good intentions_

Comment: For the majority of the people who not even know what a browser is, this is a good trade for their product. I just hope that they don't remove it from `about:config`.

Answer (score 19):

If you type `about:config` in your URL bar, and search for 'javascript' there is an entry `javascript.enabled` which you can set to false or true.

Comment: thnx buddy this worked like a charm :)

Comment: I disabled JavaScript and tried to do upvote your answer )))

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Firefox add-on "YesScript" which allows you to disable JavaScript on certain sites only.